# Change the background image when you click using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

So I have an un-pushed and a pushed button image. I want the website to show the un-pushed image. When the user clicks the button, it shows the pushed button image and then goes back to the un-pushed image when they release the click.

**HTML**

```
<div class="button"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.button{
background-image: url("images/btn-unclicked.png");
width:210px;
height:210px;}
```

**jQuery**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
$(function() {
$('.button').click(function() {
$(this).css('background-image', 'url(/images/btn-clicked.png)');
});
}):
</script>`
```

And then when the user releases the click it should go back to the image btn-unclicked. The above code is not working. I realize I have nothing for it to go back to the original image when the click is released - but not even the first part where it initially changes the image is working.

Comment: Why not just use CSS? `.button:active {...}`

Comment: are you sure your image path is correct? It says url("images/btn-unclicked.png") in css and url(/images/btn-clicked.png) in js

Comment: Definitely use CSS for this.

Comment: See I originally assumed it was a simple CSS solution. Then when I went to look it up I Googled "change background image on click" and the top 3 results were stack overflow questions that involved jQuery... Works like a charm though, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was simply using the .button:active class in CSS instead of jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the click() mouse event, which as you noted executes every time the mouse button is pressed and released.

I would recommend isherwood's comment as the best method of getting the effect you intend, but if you wish to use jQuery, there are built-in mouse events that handle what you are talking about:

[mousedown()](http://api.jquery.com/mousedown/) is sent when you click down with the mouse.

[mouseup()](http://api.jquery.com/mouseup/) is sent when you release the click.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
.button {
    background: url(http://placehold.it/80x50);
}
.button:active {
    background: url(http://placehold.it/80x50/ff0000);
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/nf23q3ua/)